# get function argument in php extension

Tags: php

i am new to php extension writing and working on php extension which will capture called functions and its arguments.
i am able to get function name using following piece of code

```
static void get_function_details(zend_execute_data *data, zend_op_array   *op_array TSRMLS_DC) 
{
   fprintf(fp,data->function_state.function->common.function_name);
}
```

However i am having difficulty in getting argument details.

i tried following piece but it did not work

```
char ** args;
char * first_arg;
args = (char**)data->function_state.arguments; 
first_arg = *args;
fprintf(fp,first_arg);
```

can anyone please give me some sample code to get function arguments.

Comment: In order to locate sample code, just check out any open source PHP extension, which should be trivial to locate on the web.